# U-SQL - Adding R dplyr package

Tags: r, azure, u-sql

One of the R model we have developed is using dplyr R Library.

U-SQL default library doesn't come with dplyr and hence we are trying to deploy it manually using code below but it doesn't work. It doesn't load this library.

U-SQL code
DEPLOY RESOURCE @"/LibDataLake/RLibraries/dplyr_0.7.8.zip";

R-Code
install.packages('dplyr ', repos = NULL)
require(dplyr)

So we tried using downloading directly from CRAN website. It does work locally but it download older version.

install.packages('dplyr')

Other issue with above approach is only works locally but it doesn't download when we tried running it via ADLS.

Does anyone successfully executed R script using U-SQL using dplyr R Library?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do it, its download the file on datalake in directory:

`usqlext\assembly\R\MRS.9.1.0.zip`

Them you unzip the file (on a machine without R installed) and execute R.exe on bin folder.

Now you can install all packages you want (with parameter dependencies = true)

```
install.packages('package_you_want', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Zip the folder again and replace the file on datalake by this you created.

Execute

`RegisterAllAssemblies.USQL`

again, and your package will be available for you!

```
library('package_you_want')
```

If get not find package error, you need this trick:

```
libpath = .libPaths()[1]
install.packages('package_you_want', lib = libpath)
```